# MYSQL need to remove random values and add values in sequence

Tags: mysql

i have this table and i have column called order it has random values like
1
2
5
7
8
12
11
9

i want to remove that and get values in a sequence
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8

is there a way to do that?

Comment: SELECT '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'

Comment: Its not clear exactly what your asking. Are you trying to change the order values for existing rows? are you just wanting to fetch the data in the order of the values?

Comment: I think he wants to convert `1 2 5 7 8 12 11 9` to `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`, ie 5>>3, 7>>4, 8>>5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to this forum..I must say that you haven't searched well for solution ..but still I would like to help you.

You can use given command to get the data according to your question

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name
ORDER BY order ;
```

Or use identity on order column at the time of creation of your table as

```
CREATE TABLE your_table_name(
    order int identity(1, 1),
    other_columns ur_choice_datatype
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question, you want to have identity column and remove existing ID column.

Try `ALTER TABLE tbl1 ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST;`

Then drop the existing identity by

```
ALTER TABLE tbl1 DROP COLUMN yourColumn;
```

If I am guessing it right, you have `1 2 5 7 8 12 11 9` because you have deleted rows with id `3 4 6 10` etc